# Mongoose update function replacing rather than pushing additional entries in React app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Schema:

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  balance: [{
    balanceDate: Date,
    newBalance: Number
  }],
  limit: Number,
});
```

Balance is an array of objects, with balanceDate and newBalance in them. Limit is just a number.

When a user posts an update, what I want to do is push another entry onto the balance array (so create another object), and update the limit.

However, every time I post the edit, it completely replaces the balance object, and doesn't push a new entry on. It does however update the limit fine.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so some advice would be appreciated.

Here is my serverless function which is called via Axios in my frontend.

```
  module.exports = async (req, res) => {

    await SubmitDebt.findById(req.query.id, function(err, submitdebt) {
      if (!submitdebt) {
        console.log(req.query.id);
        res.status(404).send("Unable to find entry to edit.");
      }
      else {
        console.log(req.query.id);
        submitdebt.newBalance = req.body.newBalance;
        submitdebt.balanceDate = req.body.balanceDate;
        submitdebt.limit = req.body.limit;

        submitdebt.save().then(submitdebt => {
          res.json("Debt successfully updated.");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).send("Debt unsuccessfully updated.");
        });
      }
    });

  };
```

And my Axios post:

```
  onSubmit = async (e) => {

      e.preventDefault();

      const newBalanceDate = new Date()

      await axios.post("/api/edit/editDebtCard",
      {
        balance: {
          newBalance: this.state.balance,
          balanceDate: newBalanceDate
        },
        limit: this.state.limit
      },
    {
      params: {
        id: this.props.match.params.id
      }
    }
  )
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }
```

Any feedback would be really appreciated!

Comment: Feedback would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add to the array, shouldn't the serverless function be something like this?

```
await SubmitDebt.findById(req.query.id, function(err, submitdebt) {
      if (!submitdebt) {
        console.log(req.query.id);
        res.status(404).send("Unable to find entry to edit.");
      }
      else {
        console.log(req.query.id);
        submitdebt.balance.push(req.body.balance);

        // and if you want to update limit as well then
        submitdebt.limit = req.body.limit;

        submitdebt.save().then(submitdebt => {
          res.json("Debt successfully updated.");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).send("Debt unsuccessfully updated.");
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Spot on. This has worked - so simple too! Thanks a lot for your help. :-)